# is there any way for us to config input parameters of operation

Tags: enterprise-architect, activity-diagram

I am a newbie of Enterprise Architect, today I have a question, 
could you please help me to answer it?

My question is "When using [Call Operation] Action, is there any way for us to config input parameters of operation?". I tried to use action pin for call argument, but it is not worked. The generated code is not added the parameter.

I attached the image too.

This question is important for me, could you please help me to answer it.

[Call and argument config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAHp0.png)

[activity diagram and generated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuzTc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the properties of the pin and select the Pin tab on the left. Now you can define the parameters if the action is a Call Operation.

[image]